# how to write log4j-gwt messages into a file instead of console?

Tags: gwt, logging, log4j

I am using log4j-gwt aud gwt's remote logging. I get the messages logged on my console as expected but did not managed to get the message print on my physical .log file.

Any idea of how I can do this?

Here is my log4j properties file (which works fine for all non-gwt related messages):

```
# CONSOLE APPENDER CONFIG [common] ---------------------------------------------------------------
log4j.appender.CONSOLE_APPENDER=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
#log4j.appender.CONSOLE_APPENDER.layout=org.apache.log4j.SimpleLayout 
log4j.appender.CONSOLE_APPENDER.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE_APPENDER.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n

# ROOT LOGGER CONFIG ----------------------------------------------------------------------
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG,ROOT_FILE_APPENDER 

log4j.appender.ROOT_FILE_APPENDER=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.ROOT_FILE_APPENDER.File=C:/log/tbps_root.log
log4j.appender.ROOT_FILE_APPENDER.MaxFileSize=20480KB
log4j.appender.ROOT_FILE_APPENDER.MaxBackupIndex=5
log4j.appender.ROOT_FILE_APPENDER.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.ROOT_FILE_APPENDER.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n


# GWT -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#These are various unseccsful attemps...
log4j.logger.com.google.gwt.logging.server.RemoteLoggingServiceUtil=DEBUG,ROOT_FILE_APPENDER
log4j.logger.com.google.gwt.logging.server.RemoteServiceServlet=DEBUG,ROOT_FILE_APPENDER
log4j.logger.com.google.gwt.logging.server.simpleRemoteHandler=DEBUG,ROOT_FILE_APPENDER
log4j.logger.com.google.gwt.logging=DEBUG,ROOT_FILE_APPENDER
log4j.logger.com.google.gwt.logging.Logging=DEBUG,ROOT_FILE_APPENDER
log4j.logger.com.google.gwt.logging.server=DEBUG,ROOT_FILE_APPENDER
```

Comment: I guess here is an answer to your question: [Save the console.log in Chrome to a file][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627113/save-the-console-log-in-chrome-to-a-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GWT-log4j and GWT's RemoteLoggingService use different loggers, [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7222124/configuring-gwt-logs-remotelogger-use-log4j-to-put-it-in-a-separate-file/10083920#10083920).  Hence, your log4j properties are not being applied to GWT's remote logger.

You can either implement your own remote logging class, or use slf4j to "bridge" the two loggers.

I recently added logs of the user's actions to a GWT application.  I first tried using GWT-log4j in conjunction with RemoteLoggingService and had this same issue.  After reading the above link I created my own logger class -- this was particularly nice as I could pass data objects to the remote logger allowing me to serialize the state of the GWT application.  This later became very useful :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I ended up implementing my own remote class as well.